# Ubuntu 11 Beta 2 update to RC and then Final

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates

I want to install Ubuntu 11 in its latest state (Beta 2)....but I don't want to reinstall everything when the Final comes out.

Can I update it from Beta 2 without reinstalling everything from a disc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can update from the Beta.

According to the [release schedule](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Ubuntu-11-04-Release-Schedule-Changed-183747.shtml), there is no longer an RC and the final will be the next release, 28th April.

To update to the latest release version when it releases you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `update-manager -d`

This will open the update manager with the ability to look for any distribution upgrades.

As a note. It's not wise to update to the latest version from a Beta and to avoid any problems will be better to install the final release as a fresh install.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea? It's only 7 days so I can wait...

Comment: Updating doesn't usually update EVERYTHING in the distribution, it could leave something behind which could cause a problem. All I'm stating is that a fresh install normally solves all problems

Comment: Got it. I will wait until the final release. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

keep updating your machine and you will be upgraded to release candidate
Alternatively you can do it from the command line

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

(but this will work only after the RC is released )